# Spread operator error on react and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function:

```
handleMarkerClick(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({
        markers: this.state.markers.map(marker => {
            if (marker === targetMarker) {
                return {
                    ...marker, //  error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

                    showInfo: true, // error TS1005: ',' expected.
                }; // error TS1135: Argument expression expected, error TS1005: ')' expected.
            }
            return marker; //  error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
        }), // Declaration or statement expected.
    });
}
```

and I see many errors:

- Property assignment expected.
- ',' expected.
- Argument expression expected.
- You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
      | exports.__esModule = true;
      | exports["default"] = PopUpInfoWindowExample;
      | return marker;

But when I delete '...' near 'marker' my function wasn't work correct.

I do this:

```
    handleMarkerClick(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({
        markers: this.state.markers.map(marker => {
            if (marker === targetMarker) {
                return {
                    marker, // delete ...
                    showInfo: true,
                };
            }
            return marker;
        }),
    });
}
```

Why? What I can do to get right function?

Comment: Is `marker` a string?

Comment: marker is an element of array (markers) - it's react-google-maps https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/basics/pop-up-window

Comment: Is `targetMarker` an array? What is expected result of `marker === targetMarker` and  `...marker`?

Comment: Can you please show us the line numbers (and corresponding line in your post) for each error you're receiving?

Comment: targetMarker is a target marker (one) . marker === targetMarker - is a function to check clickable marker of markers array.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? The functionality you're using was only recently released in typescript 2.1

Comment: 2.0.3 , And what I can do to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

If `marker` is an object then instead of using the spread operator you can try using `Object.assign()`. Here's an example:

```
marker = Object.assign({}, marker);
```